# Electron mean free path as a function of pressure

Tags: mean-free-path

How do I calculate electron beam mean free path as a function of vacuum pressure? For example, if I am pumping a vacuum system down and have an electron beam of known energy, what is the mean free path of electrons in the beam as pressure lowers? I understand basic mean free path equations on the molecular level, but I assume it would be incorrect to plug in classical electron diameter for finding cross section collision area between an electron and nitrogen molecule.

If there is no simple function for this, could someone give estimates of electron mean free path at pressures of 10 to 0.1 mTorr? What is the general scale of electron mean free path at these pressures (centimeters, meters, kilometers)?

Comment: It is the molecule size that defines the cross-section. From the geometry, the collisional mean-free-path is $\lambda = 1/(n \sigma)$ where sigma is $\sim \pi d^2$, d is the diameter of the molecule, n the number density of molecules.

Comment: @MaximUmansky that's a core of an answer.